# How do I remove Windows Vista off my Ubuntu laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall, windows-vista

I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed as a dual boot and I no longer want Windows Vista on my laptop. What is the easiest way to remove Vista from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

To remove Windows all you need to do is to delete the Windows partition. Before you begin I suggest you do a complete back up just in case you delete the  wrong partition!

1. Insert the live CD or USB for Ubuntu and open the partition manager(Gparted)
2. Find all the Windows partitions, right click and Delete it.(Make sure you are not deleting the wrong partition!)
3. Now right click on the Linux partition and choose Re size option and include the deleted windows partition.
4. Select the Apply all Operation.

After deleting the partition if you still find any Windows entries in the grub go to the Linux terminate and type `sudo update-grub` and you are good to go!